# Invalid location of tag (ul) & (table)

Tags: html, eclipse, tags, location

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Achievements</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>수료증 및 수상 내역</h2>
  <hr>
  <ul>
    <h3><li>수료증</li></h3>
    <table border="1"> 
  <tr>
    <th>과목명</th>
    <th>교수명</th>
    <th>대학명</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Programming for Everybody(Getting Started with Python)</td>
    <td>Charles Severance</td>
    <td>University of Michigan</td>
  </tr>
  </table>  
      <h3><li>수상내역</li></h3>
      <table border="1">
    <tr>
    <th>대회명</th>
    <th>수상일</th>    
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>The 5th MIRROR Essay Contest</td>
    <td>11/23/15</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</ul>
  <hr>
  <a href="main.html">메인으로</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using Eclipse Jee Mars btw, and I get warnings saying "Multiple annotations found at this line: Invalid location of tag (h3), Invalid location of tag (h3)" and "Invalid location of (table)". When I open the file through Internet explorer it works fine. What's the problem and how should I fix it?

Comment: "works fine" is in the eye of the beholder. Different browsers react differently to errors! So it's best to not have errors at all. Don't go by what your browser outputs, go by what the validator says. If you have no errors, it will display correctly in all the browsers.